# How do I change the text color and background of a png?

Tags: png

I tried the quick selection tool but I notice some jaggies and it's not crisp. Does anyone know a way? I want to turn a png's text white and the background another solid color.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Coulnd't you just retype some white text on a solid coloured background?  Why do you need to edit an already existing raster image of text? What software are you using? You say you can see jagged edges, but is that at 100% or did you zoom in? Zooming in on raster images will show the pixels.  Please [edit](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/121652/edit) your question and add more details, and perhaps consider sharing an image showing the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the png is too low res to capture the effect you are going for with the magic wand. Someone may have a better answer for you, but I've had success with this hack when I've been given a client logo that is unsuitable for what I need and they don't have a good library of brand assets to send me anything else.

For example, if you have a blue logo on a white background you can use Brightness/Contrast to increase contrast to 100, and decrease brightness to 0.
This should give you a black logo on a white background. 
Then select Image>Adjustments>Invert and you'll have a white logo on a black background.
Choose Image>Adjust>Hue/Saturation. 
Check the box in the bottom right that says Colorize.
Bump up the Saturation to 100. 
Adjust the Lightness upwards (at least +25 as a guess)
Then slide the Hue slider til you get the color you want.